# Cursor is looping but repeats only the first value

Tags: android, listview, while-loop, cursor

I created a loop that will get the data from my cursor, however I noticed that even though it is looping(with the correct count) it only shows the first value.

```
int vv = 0;
  if ((CR3.moveToFirst()) || CR3.getCount() !=0){


            while (CR3.isAfterLast() == false) {
                vendoName[vv] = CR3.getString(0);
                vendoEsch[vv] = CR3.getString(1);
                vendoAsch[vv] = CR3.getString(2);
                vendoTag[vv] = CR3.getString(3);                    
                vv++;
                CR3.moveToNext();   
        }}
```

and when I call all my data( I only need the first three records)

```
ArrayList<SearchResults2> results2 = new ArrayList<SearchResults2>();
SearchResults2 sr2 = new SearchResults2();
     for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
     {

     sr2.setName(vendoName[j]);
     sr2.setEsch(vendoEsch[j]);
     sr2.setAsch(vendoAsch[j]);
     sr2.setTag(vendoTag[j]);
     results2.add(sr2);
     }
```

I am putting inside a listview, when I check, it is showing always the first data.

This is an example I used as a reference to my code(It's almost the same except that I used an array to put my data from)
http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Am I doing something wrong which is why it is only getting the first piece of data?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not easier to do something like this (if you don't need more than 3 results):

```
ArrayList<SearchResults2> results2 = new ArrayList<SearchResults2>();
CR3.moveToFirst();
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    SearchResults2 sr2 = new SearchResults2();
    sr2.setName(CR3.getString(0));
    sr2.setEsch(CR3.getString(1));
    sr2.setAsch(CR3.getString(2));
    sr2.setTag(CR3.getString(3));
    results2.add(sr2);
    CR3.moveToNext();
}
```

I think that maybe the cursor doesn't iterate properly through your results in your `while`-loop and that's why you become one and the same result for the three items

Comment: Would this work if I'm doing it inside an asynchronous task? sorry I forgot to mention it in my question?

Comment: I think that it will, but I don't try it yet in an asynchronous task, but there seems to be no reasons for problems in an asynchronous task